# managing iboutlets in base view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Every UIViewController of my app is using the UITextField delegates, like:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField {

    self.responder = textField;

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {

double elementYPosition = self.responder.frame.origin.y;
double elementHeight = self.responder.frame.size.height;
double scrollYPosition = self.scrollView.contentOffset.y;
/* some logic */

}
```

Now I'm trying to create a base view controller, so I can inherit use it all around, reusing the methods. The `responder` property in the base view controller works just fine, because the UITextField delegate set its value, but the scrollview is a IBOutlet, and I'm not really sure how to design this base class:

```
#import "ViewControllerBase.h"

@interface ViewControllerBase ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIView* responder;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView; /* ??? */

@end

@implementation ViewControllerBase

-- methods

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the subclass header:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

In the subclass load method:

```
self.scrollView = (UIScrollView *)self.view.subviews[0];
```

But it only works because my view controllers are always in the following format:

```
UIViewController (self)
  UIView (self.view)
    UIScrollView (self.view.subviews[0])
      UILabel
      UIElement
    UIElement
    UIElement
```